# inmobi ads integration in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, inmobi

I am trying to integrat inMobi ads in my iphone application. inmobi requires the live iphone app url in the configuration. As my app is not published on itunes yet, I am using url of another app which is live. My plan was to change the url in inmobi configuration with the correct url once my app is released

When I try to load the inmobi ad, the response goes into didFailRequestWithError. the error message is -

*"Unable to load__Error Domain=Invalid request. This could be due to an invalid app-id, or the app-id might not be in the Active state."*

is this error message due to wrong url? If yes then how can I enable inmobi in version 1.0 of my app and also test it to make sure that it is configured correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly test out ads on an app that is not live on the iTunes store.

It would be helpful if you could post some code here. You should check two things though:

1. The property ID you are using is indeed correct.
2. You have enabled your Property in test mode. There is a guide available [here](http://www.inmobi.com/support/article/?id=23382291&title=Setting%20up%20publisher%20diagnostics)